# mariadb JSON_UNQUOTE get's ignored on special characters

Tags: mysql, json, mariadb

I'm using MariaDB 10.2.7 to select a value from a JSON document. After investigating a bit i red that i have to extract and unquote the results. But now i encounter the following issue when using this method. I have a latin1_swedish_ci table with a field `title`. The contents of this field is:

`{"en":"Lorum Ipsum","sv":"Börk Börk Börksum"}`

I select the contents of the row like this:

`SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(title, '$.sv')) FROM...`

Now, when I select the english version i get the expected results: 
`Lorum Ipsum` But if I select the swedish version, the double quoutes are still around the result `"Börk Börk Börksum"` so it seems like JSON_UNQUOTE just ignores the quotes. Is this a known issue or am I missing something?

Comment: This seems like a bug. In MySQL 5.7 the bug does not appear [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u3HU5tUvgZm3dzjaCfdgCg/0). Workaround may be to change the collation [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=ad03e73da3c2d1d5d22a04c5ba9a1bed).

Comment: Thank you wchiquito, the workaround works perfect. Thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: Bug reported and confirmed, see [JSON_UNQUOTE returns incorrect results depending on the collation](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-14301).

Comment: I think I found a similar issue, I commented on the issue above. Looks like it's still unresolved?

Answer (score 0):

For those who haven't paid attention to wchiquito's comment link:

```
SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(title, '$.sv') AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8mb4)) FROM...
```